# CSS: How to shrink first div in container instead of going outside of container

Tags: css

User can change width of container, it can be shorter than space needed for both containers. What I need is shrink first container if such situation happens. Here expected result: "First div con...Second div content". Is there possible way to do it for all modern browsers? (latest Chrome, Firefox and IE 11 needed).
Here html code from example "https://plnkr.co/edit/rH3ABKvFRltvAL1rXqkr?p=preview":

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">first div content</div>
  <div class="second">second div content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox:

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap
}
.first {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">first div content</div>
  <div class="second">second div content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to put "Third div" just after first one and apply for it the same rules as for second? (for example "First...SecondThird" and "First content Second       Third" will be valid cases).

Comment: Yes, flexbox allows you to reorder, use `.first{order:1} .second{order:3} .third{order:2}`

Comment: Problem is not order, problem is that it should be displayed without indent, I've describe question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484375/css-how-to-shrink-first-div-in-container-instead-of-going-outside-of-container