# CSS: How to shrink first div in container instead of going outside of container (second container should be shown just after first)

Tags: css

I've asked similar question here: [CSS: How to shrink first div in container instead of going outside of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483109/css-how-to-shrink-first-div-in-container-instead-of-going-outside-of-container), but this question is more difficult: User can change width of container, it can be shorter than space needed for 3 containers. What I need is shrink first container if such situation happens, also second container should be displayed just after first. Here expected result: "First div con...Second div content Third div content". Is there possible way to do it for all modern browsers? (latest Chrome, Firefox and IE 11 needed). Here html code from example "https://plnkr.co/edit/9FGmNOHYxjtsQMUpeVfm?p=preview":

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">First div content</div>
  <div class="second">Second div content</div>
  <div class="third">Third div content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use the max-width with percentage value like `max-width: 20%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are asking *from this question alone* but from the details of the other question it still seems as though flexbox is the solution as described by Oriol

```css
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.first {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding-right: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.third {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">first div content</div>
  <div class="second first">second div content</div>
  <div class="third">third div content</div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/bd7uk33d/)

Comment: Is there any way to do it without overflow hidden? Here example of what I've done https://plnkr.co/edit/Fg5P96r75soAVlDUf1LG?p=preview,  but it isn't working for IE 11.