# CSS: How to shrink first div in container instead of going outside of container without overflow hidden in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I've asked similar question here: [CSS: How to shrink first div in container instead of going outside of container (second container should be shown just after first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484375/css-how-to-shrink-first-div-in-container-instead-of-going-outside-of-container), but that's one is more difficult, I find out that I can't use overflow hidden for it because there are popup in elements. Here description: I have several containers and need shrink only first div if not enough space for all of them, here example which works perfectly for me in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE: https://plnkr.co/edit/Fg5P96r75soAVlDUf1LG?p=preview:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
  <div class="first">first div content</div>
  <div class="second">second div content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">third div content</div>
</div>
```

Is there any simple solution to fix it in IE 11?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: How to shrink first div in container instead of going outside of container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483109/css-how-to-shrink-first-div-in-container-instead-of-going-outside-of-container)

Comment: That “similar question” you are referring to was itself a duplicate of that first one already. Please don’t create one new question after another, if it is basically still about the same topic/problem – instead, edit your original question, if you have to add anything to the problem description or requirements.

Comment: But the original question was answered correctly, I tried it and found that it wasn't enough, because of it I've created new question and after that this.

Comment: So what’s the (significant) difference between version 2 of your question, and this version 3 here then?

Comment: I said nothing about significant difference, but question is different because here solution should not use hiding of overflow.

Comment: Well that little detail could still as well have been edited into version 2 of your question –